# Ошибка синтаксиса UPDATE

Tags: c#, база-данных, access, datagridview

Делаю запрос к таблице из access. После выполнения такого запроса выдает ошибку синтаксиса UPDATE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выполняется запрос UPDATE в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица в БД выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неужели нельзя было тексты команд и кода привести, а не картинки? Проблемы в запросе: `update [Соц_паспорт_класса] SET [Кол-во] = 12 where [№] = 33`.
1) Берите в [] все, что содержит недопустимые символы
2) Полагаю, что [Кол-во] - число. Поэтому 12 в кавычки брать не надо

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашелся. Ошибка Автору 0 лет. Просто я назвал столбец "Кол-во", а надо было "Кол_Во", так как access не поддерживает в название столбца ПРОБЕЛ и -.

Comment: Вообще не могу понять что означает Ваша вставка "Ошибка Автору 0 лет." Как она относится к вопросу или ответу. Если есть какие-то важные замечания к вопросу - вносите их в вопрос. В решении же должно быть решение.

Comment: удалите этот ответ